# Ruby on Rails5: Filtering users by City / Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filtering, ruby-on-rails-5, country, city

what is the best way to structure Location information for users? I need to be able filter hundreds of users by City/Country.

Currently I have created a free-text string for location as I could not find any gem for whole cities grouped under countries. Btw this is a custom scaffold, not devise.

[image]

Should I just enter as free-text as in **city, country** and then filter based on that string with alike?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend usage of free-tex input because you will get different possible entries for the same city and country which will make filteration an impossible task. It is always better to use a drop down list.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/) is a full list of countries and cities using java script.

change the location attribute with two attributes `country` and `state` and use the previous list to fill them.

Comment: ah! I have been looking for such javascript! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have structured data (i.e., address, city, state, country) for your users, you can filter on those. For example:

```
WHERE city || ', ' || country ILIKE ?
```

If you don't, you can still try that assuming freeform location information on your users table (you weren't clear on the database schema):

```
WHERE location ILIKE ?
```

Ideally you'd split up the city and country and filter separately:

```
WHERE city ILIKE ? AND country ILIKE ?
```

Hundreds shouldn't be much of a performance issue but you can definitely build indexes for either of those:

```
CREATE INDEX city_country_on_users ON users(city || ', ' || country);
CREATE INDEX city_country_on_users ON users(location);
CREATE INDEX city_country_on_users ON users(city, country);
```

respectively

Comment: Thanks Caleb! So I should have 2 separate text inputs for **City** and **Country** in my User table. right? I will type this inputs as I add users and by this way the city/country data will grow in the table... Later I can pull this as a clickable filter. So I dont really need a separate table for city/location, right?